# How do I pass variables from Airflow to (GCP) Dataform?

Tags: sql, airflow, sqlx, dataform

I have an existing data pipeline in Airflow (through Google Cloud Composer) in which I execute Python and SQL-based tasks. Now, I am working on implementing it into Dataform (Google Cloud-version - not Dataform.co, if that matters).

When I use my SQL-based tasks I can easily "catch" and use the parameters with `{{params.variable}}`. For example if I pass the variables `country`  and `city` from Airflow, I currently do this in the SQL-file called by the Airflow DAG:

`SELECT id, name FROM my_{{params.country}}_dataset.abc123_{{params.city}}_table`

in order to be able to run the same SQL-script for several countries and cities in Airflow.

What is the equivalence in Dataform / sqlx? I preferrably want to use this is in the source/config in which I define my data sources, in Dataform.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your query as:

```sql
SELECT id, name FROM my_${dataform.projectConfig.vars.country}_dataset.abc123_{dataform.projectConfig.vars.city}_table
```

Then you can provide the variables default values in the `dataform.json` file:

```json
{
  ...
  "vars": {
    "country": "some_country",
    "city": "some_city",
  },
  ...
}
```

and override them using dataform CLI:

```bash
dataform run --vars=country=another_country,city=another_city
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a interesting take on it but I am not really sure if this solves my problem though of passing a variable from Airflow, unless Airflow can control the dataform CLI but it seems like a very hacky solution in that case.

Answer (score 1):

To execute your dataform code, you first need to compile it. Fortunately you can do it through Airflow using the `DataformCreateCompilationResultOperator`. This Airflow Operator take a parameter called `compilation_result`. This parameter is where you can pass your variables (those from the `dataform.json`).

Below an example :

```py
compilation_result = {
    "code_compilation_config": {"default_schema": DEFAULT_SCHEMA},
    "vars": {
        "country": some_country,
        "city": some_city
    }
}

DataformCreateCompilationResultOperator(
    task_id="create_compilation_result",
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    region=DATAFORM_REGION,
    repository_id=DATAFORM_REPOSITORY_ID,
    compilation_result=compilation_result,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    timeout=None

)
```

Then you can use the `DataformCreateWorkflowInvocationOperator` to execute you workflow :

```py
create_workflow_invocation = DataformCreateWorkflowInvocationOperator(
    task_id='create_workflow_invocation',
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    region=DATAFORM_REGION,
    repository_id=DATAFORM_REPOSITORY_ID,
    workflow_invocation={
        "compilation_result": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_compilation_result')['name'] }}"
    },
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    timeout=None
)
```

Comment: Do you know if I could use that method to pass a date (ds_nodash) that then dataform can use as a filter for an incremental table?

Comment: Unfortunately the field `compilation_result` isn't templated. However, what you can do is to use the operator (DataformCreateCompilationResultOperator) inside a TaskFlow-decorated @task which is a custom python function. In this function you can then update `compilation_result`. Then call the method `execute` to execute the dataform operator.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the method provided by Lucas. It worked, but I had to change `compilation_result` to

```
compilation_result = {
    "code_compilation_config": {
        "default_schema": DEFAULT_SCHEMA,
        "vars": {"country": some_country, "city": some_city},
    },
}
```

BTW, my version of google provider is `apache-airflow-providers-google==8.9.0`

ref https://cloud.google.com/dataform/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.repositories.compilationResults#codecompilationconfig